# Resize efi partition on windows

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, efi

I have windows 8.1

How could I resize Efi partition on Windows because I don't have any other operating system
please help

Comment: This is the same for newer versions of Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use an live image of GParted which you can find here: http://gparted.org/

Burn to CD or use a USB Drive and boot from it.